# MediaBrowserService where to get the media files in onLoadChildren

Tags: java, android, audio-player, mediabrowserservice, android-music-player

I'm trying to make a MediaBrowserService. In the past when I want to display all the music files actually on the device, I would use a ContentResolver and load a cursor from the MediaStore.

I can't figure out where I am supposed to do this in a MediaBrowserService.

There is the method: onLoadChildren

The examples I find look like this:

```
    @Override
public void onLoadChildren(
        @NonNull final String parentMediaId,
        @NonNull final Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) {
    result.sendResult(MusicLibrary.getMediaItems());
}
```

My question is, do I use my ContentResolver cursor within this method to return a list of MediaItems? Or is there some other internal method to use to go through the device and get all the music files?
Only examples I see online are streaming services which do an HTTP call to get a song list, or they just hard code fake songs to display for testing. I'm trying to allow the service to browse music files that are on the device itself.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to do the exactly same thing in my app, hitting the same wall as you. Finally I figured out how to do it using the Android's new [Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/). You do have to use a cursor with a ContentResolver at the service side in order to fetch the media items on the device, but in order to not iterate all the cursor's records just to return the children in the onLoadChildren() method, I use the paging library to return only the chunks the user is interested in this moment at the client/UI side. You can read about it in a [post](https://medium.com/@shevach/how-to-paginate-mediabrowserservice-e4fdc902ff2) I wrote, where I also demonstrate the concept with code samples.